# How to see a friendly report of unit tests using .Net Core and coverlet?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, .net-core, automated-tests, code-coverage

I'm using coverlet and .Net Core to develop an API, I started to make unit tests (the only tool I've found for .Net Core was coverlet).

I got the coverage, but I only can get files like `json`, `xml` etc.

I would need to see an HTML or something more visual to be able to handle the tests fastly.

Here is my current output on terminal:

```
+---------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| Module                    | Line   | Branch | Method |
+---------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| rede-merchants-cancel-api | 12,5%  | 0%     | 16,7%  |
+---------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

And a part of the output with `json`:

```
"Program.cs": {
  "Program": {
    "System.Void rede_merchants_cancel_api.Program::Main(System.String[])": {
      "Lines": {
        "9": 0,
        "10": 0,
        "11": 0
      },
      "Branches": []
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHost rede_merchants_cancel_api.Program::BuildWebHost(System.String[])": {
      "Lines": {
        "14": 0,
        "15": 0,
        "16": 0
      },
      "Branches": []
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found an answer, what I tried first was using the [docker-dotnet-sonarscanner](https://github.com/burakince/docker-dotnet-sonarscanner), but I couldn't setting that very well, then I adopted another approach:

1. Install [coverlet](https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet), which gives me the code coverage for .Net Core in many formats: `json` (default), `lcov`, `opencover` and `cobertura`.
2. Install a plugin for VSCode where I could see the code coverage in a nice way, and its name is [coverage-gutters](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryanluker.vscode-coverage-gutters).
3. Use the command available on the coverlet docs to output the code coverage with the `lcov` format, to be able to use with the plugin of code coverage.
4. Extra - Use a plugin to run the tests on VSCode instead of CLI (I didn't tried that), with [.Net Test Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.dotnet-test-explorer) it's possible but I think it would be necessary to change the command to be able to output what you need.

Comment: how to use coverage gutters to view report as it only supports viewing html

Comment: @drowhunter You can view html inside VSCode or other editors

Answer (score 10):

In case you would like to see a nice and clean HTML report from your code coverage result with source code you should try Daniel Palme's [ReportGenerator](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator). Coverlet can generate     `cobertura` type XML report and ReportGenerator can generate an HTML report out of it. [Here](https://medium.com/bluekiri/code-coverage-in-vsts-with-xunit-coverlet-and-reportgenerator-be2a64cd9c2f) you can find an awesome step-by-step tutorial about how to use coverlet and ReportGenerator. Cobertura report can easily processed with [this](https://plugins.jenkins.io/cobertura) Jenkins plugin during your CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: Method report needs payment https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/65d31c6f41bcb73061c9d314d62abafb#file-reportgenerator-needs-payment-md